# Python: Date comparing works in Spyder but not in Console

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, spyder

i have written a little csv parser based on pandas.
It works like a charm in Spyder 3. 
Yesterday i tried to put it into production and run it with a .bat file, like:

`python my_parser.py`

In the console it doesn't work at all.
Pandas behaves different: The read_csv method lost the "quotechar" keyword argument, for example.

Especially date comparisons break all the time.

I read the dates with pandas as per

`pd.read_csv(parse_dates=[col3, col5, col8])`

Then i try a date calculation by substracting `pd.to_datetime('now')`

I tested everything, and as said, in Spyder no failure is thrown, it works and produces results as it should be.
As soon as i start it in the console, he throws type errors. 
The most often one of the two dates is a mere string and the other stays a datetime, so the minus operation fails.

I could now rewrite the code and find a procedure that works in both, Spyder and console.

However, i prefer to ask you guys here:

What could be a possible reason that spyder and the console python behave completely different from each other?

It's really annoying to debug code that does not throw any failures, so i really would like to understand the cause.

Comment: have you tried running it in the anaconda terminal as well? I a guessing you are using Windows right?

Comment: I just tried to run it with pythonw instead python. With Pythonw it works. I am not aware about any installation differences between the two. I would normally prefer python to get the outputs if there are any.

Comment: .... and this was not right: it doesn't show the exceptions because it is pythonw, but nevertheless, it doesn't work. However it works if I double click the python file. Now I am really lost! Yes, I use Windows 7, I use Python 2.7.

Comment: Do you have several Python installations or Anaconda environments?

Comment: Thanks for that tip, that worked. I cleanly disinstalled all of python and installed only one single version. Now it works.  That's quite a thing that it begins to behave so strange if there are several versions installed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was related to having several python installations on my PC. After removing all of it and installing a single instance, it was working well. Thanks for the tipp, Carlos Cordoba!